# How can I use CKEditor without a config.js file?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I just started using CKEditor and had some questions on how to integrate this with AngularJS. The following fiddle was given to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/fMC2p/

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>CKEditor 4.2:</h3>

    <textarea data-ng-model="ckContent" data-ck-editor></textarea>
    <br />
    <textarea data-ng-model="ckContent" data-ck-editor></textarea>
    <textarea data-ng-model="ckContent"></textarea>
    <pre>{{ckContent}}</pre>
</div>
```

I had previously used a config.js but cannot see one used in this fiddle. Can someone explain how it's possible. I thought it was necessary to have the config.js and many other files present.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is dynamically loading all necessary files, including `config.js`. In your case, a  [default config](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.2/config.js?t=D6ID) is loaded. You can load a different one with [`config.customConfig`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-customConfig):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'myfield', { 
    customConfig: 'pathToYourConfig.js' 
} );
```